# Why I showed a mistake when downloading the Laravel project and how to solve it

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-9

create-project laravel/laravel EduOnline
Creating a "laravel/laravel" project at "./EduOnline"
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Installing laravel/laravel (v9.5.2)

- Installing laravel/laravel (v9.5.2): Extracting archive
  Created project in C:\xampp\htdocs\EduOnline

> @php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
> Loading composer repositories with package information
> Updating dependencies
> Lock file operations: 108 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

- Locking brick/math (0.10.2)
- Locking dflydev/dot-access-data (v3.0.2)
- Locking doctrine/inflector (2.0.6)
- Locking doctrine/instantiator (2.0.0)
- Locking doctrine/lexer (3.0.0)
- Locking dragonmantank/cron-expression (v3.3.2)
- Locking egulias/email-validator (4.0.1)
- Locking fakerphp/faker (v1.21.0)
- Locking filp/whoops (2.14.6)
- Locking fruitcake/php-cors (v1.2.0)
- Locking graham-campbell/result-type (v1.1.0)
- Locking guzzlehttp/guzzle (7.5.0)
- Locking guzzlehttp/promises (1.5.2)
- Locking guzzlehttp/psr7 (2.4.3)
- Locking guzzlehttp/uri-template (v1.0.1)
- Locking hamcrest/hamcrest-php (v2.0.1)
- Locking laravel/framework (v9.51.0)
- Locking laravel/pint (v1.4.1)
- Locking laravel/sail (v1.20.0)
- Locking laravel/sanctum (v3.2.1)
- Locking laravel/serializable-closure (v1.3.0)
- Locking laravel/tinker (v2.8.0)
- Locking league/commonmark (2.3.8)
- Locking league/config (v1.2.0)
- Locking league/flysystem (3.12.2)
- Locking league/mime-type-detection (1.11.0)
- Locking mockery/mockery (1.5.1)
- Locking monolog/monolog (2.9.1)
- Locking myclabs/deep-copy (1.11.0)
- Locking nesbot/carbon (2.66.0)
- Locking nette/schema (v1.2.3)
- Locking nette/utils (v4.0.0)
- Locking nikic/php-parser (v4.15.3)
- Locking nunomaduro/collision (v6.4.0)
- Locking nunomaduro/termwind (v1.15.0)
- Locking phar-io/manifest (2.0.3)
- Locking phar-io/version (3.2.1)
- Locking phpoption/phpoption (1.9.0)
- Locking phpunit/php-code-coverage (9.2.24)
- Locking phpunit/php-file-iterator (3.0.6)
- Locking phpunit/php-invoker (3.1.1)
- Locking phpunit/php-text-template (2.0.4)
- Locking phpunit/php-timer (5.0.3)
- Locking phpunit/phpunit (9.6.3)
- Locking psr/container (2.0.2)
- Locking psr/event-dispatcher (1.0.0)
- Locking psr/http-client (1.0.1)
- Locking psr/http-factory (1.0.1)
- Locking psr/http-message (1.0.1)
- Locking psr/log (3.0.0)
- Locking psr/simple-cache (3.0.0)
- Locking psy/psysh (v0.11.12)
- Locking ralouphie/getallheaders (3.0.3)
- Locking ramsey/collection (2.0.0)
- Locking ramsey/uuid (4.7.3)
- Locking sebastian/cli-parser (1.0.1)
- Locking sebastian/code-unit (1.0.8)
- Locking sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup (2.0.3)
- Locking sebastian/comparator (4.0.8)
- Locking sebastian/complexity (2.0.2)
- Locking sebastian/diff (4.0.4)
- Locking sebastian/environment (5.1.5)
- Locking sebastian/exporter (4.0.5)
- Locking sebastian/global-state (5.0.5)
- Locking sebastian/lines-of-code (1.0.3)
- Locking sebastian/object-enumerator (4.0.4)
- Locking sebastian/object-reflector (2.0.4)
- Locking sebastian/recursion-context (4.0.5)
- Locking sebastian/resource-operations (3.0.3)
- Locking sebastian/type (3.2.1)
- Locking sebastian/version (3.0.2)
- Locking spatie/backtrace (1.2.1)
- Locking spatie/flare-client-php (1.3.5)
- Locking spatie/ignition (1.4.3)
- Locking spatie/laravel-ignition (1.6.4)
- Locking symfony/console (v6.2.5)
- Locking symfony/css-selector (v6.2.5)
- Locking symfony/deprecation-contracts (v3.2.0)
- Locking symfony/error-handler (v6.2.5)
- Locking symfony/event-dispatcher (v6.2.5)
- Locking symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts (v3.2.0)
- Locking symfony/finder (v6.2.5)
- Locking symfony/http-foundation (v6.2.6)
- Locking symfony/http-kernel (v6.2.6)
- Locking symfony/mailer (v6.2.5)
- Locking symfony/mime (v6.2.5)
- Locking symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.27.0)
- Locking symfony/polyfill-intl-grapheme (v1.27.0)
- Locking symfony/polyfill-intl-idn (v1.27.0)
- Locking symfony/polyfill-intl-normalizer (v1.27.0)
- Locking symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.27.0)
- Locking symfony/polyfill-php72 (v1.27.0)
- Locking symfony/polyfill-php80 (v1.27.0)
- Locking symfony/polyfill-uuid (v1.27.0)
- Locking symfony/process (v6.2.5)
- Locking symfony/routing (v6.2.5)
- Locking symfony/service-contracts (v3.2.0)
- Locking symfony/string (v6.2.5)
- Locking symfony/translation (v6.2.5)
- Locking symfony/translation-contracts (v3.2.0)
- Locking symfony/uid (v6.2.5)
- Locking symfony/var-dumper (v6.2.5)
- Locking symfony/yaml (v6.2.5)
- Locking theseer/tokenizer (1.2.1)
- Locking tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles (2.2.6)
- Locking vlucas/phpdotenv (v5.5.0)
- Locking voku/portable-ascii (2.0.1)
- Locking webmozart/assert (1.11.0)
  Writing lock file
  Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
  Package operations: 108 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
- Installing doctrine/inflector (2.0.6): Extracting archive
- Installing doctrine/lexer (3.0.0): Extracting archive
- Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.27.0): Extracting archive
- Installing webmozart/assert (1.11.0): Extracting archive
- Installing dragonmantank/cron-expression (v3.3.2): Extracting archive
- Installing symfony/deprecation-contracts (v3.2.0): Extracting archive
- Installing psr/container (2.0.2): Extracting archive
- Installing fakerphp/faker (v1.21.0): Extracting archive
- Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.27.0): Extracting archive
- Installing symfony/http-foundation (v6.2.6): Extracting archive
- Installing fruitcake/php-cors (v1.2.0): Extracting archive
- Installing psr/http-message (1.0.1): Extracting archive
- Installing psr/http-client (1.0.1): Extracting archive
- Installing ralouphie/getallheaders (3.0.3): Extracting archive
- Installing psr/http-factory (1.0.1): Extracting archive
- Installing guzzlehttp/psr7 (2.4.3): Extracting archive
- Installing guzzlehttp/promises (1.5.2): Extracting archive
- Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (7.5.0): Extracting archive
- Installing symfony/polyfill-php80 (v1.27.0): Extracting archive
- Installing guzzlehttp/uri-template (v1.0.1): Extracting archive
- Installing laravel/pint (v1.4.1): Extracting archive
- Installing symfony/yaml (v6.2.5): Extracting archive
- Installing voku/portable-ascii (2.0.1): Extracting archive
- Installing phpoption/phpoption (1.9.0): Extracting archive
- Installing graham-campbell/result-type (v1.1.0): Extracting archive
- Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v5.5.0): Extracting archive
- Installing symfony/css-selector (v6.2.5): Extracting archive
- Installing tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles (2.2.6): Extracting archive
- Installing symfony/var-dumper (v6.2.5): Extracting archive
- Installing symfony/polyfill-uuid (v1.27.0): Extracting archive
- Installing symfony/uid (v6.2.5): Extracting archive
- Installing symfony/routing (v6.2.5): Extracting archive
- Installing symfony/process (v6.2.5): Extracting archive
- Installing symfony/polyfill-php72 (v1.27.0): Extracting archive
- Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-normalizer (v1.27.0): Extracting archive
- Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-idn (v1.27.0): Extracting archive
- Installing symfony/mime (v6.2.5): Extracting archive
- Installing symfony/service-contracts (v3.2.0): Extracting archive
- Installing psr/event-dispatcher (1.0.0): Extracting archive
- Installing symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts (v3.2.0): Extracting archive
- Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v6.2.5): Extracting archive
- Installing psr/log (3.0.0): Extracting archive
- Installing egulias/email-validator (4.0.1): Extracting archive
- Installing symfony/mailer (v6.2.5): Extracting archive
- Installing symfony/error-handler (v6.2.5): Extracting archive
- Installing symfony/http-kernel (v6.2.6): Extracting archive
- Installing symfony/finder (v6.2.5): Extracting archive
- Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-grapheme (v1.27.0): Extracting archive
- Installing symfony/string (v6.2.5): Extracting archive
- Installing symfony/console (v6.2.5): Extracting archive
- Installing ramsey/collection (2.0.0): Extracting archive
- Installing brick/math (0.10.2): Extracting archive
- Installing ramsey/uuid (4.7.3): Extracting archive
- Installing psr/simple-cache (3.0.0): Extracting archive
- Installing nunomaduro/termwind (v1.15.0): Extracting archive
- Installing symfony/translation-contracts (v3.2.0): Extracting archive
- Installing symfony/translation (v6.2.5): Extracting archive
- Installing nesbot/carbon (2.66.0): Extracting archive
- Installing monolog/monolog (2.9.1): Extracting archive
- Installing league/mime-type-detection (1.11.0): Extracting archive
- Installing league/flysystem (3.12.2): Extracting archive
- Installing nette/utils (v4.0.0): Extracting archive
- Installing nette/schema (v1.2.3): Extracting archive
- Installing dflydev/dot-access-data (v3.0.2): Extracting archive
- Installing league/config (v1.2.0): Extracting archive
- Installing league/commonmark (2.3.8): Extracting archive
- Installing laravel/serializable-closure (v1.3.0): Extracting archive
- Installing laravel/framework (v9.51.0): Extracting archive
- Installing laravel/sail (v1.20.0): Extracting archive
- Installing laravel/sanctum (v3.2.1): Extracting archive
- Installing nikic/php-parser (v4.15.3): Extracting archive
- Installing psy/psysh (v0.11.12): Extracting archive
- Installing laravel/tinker (v2.8.0): Extracting archive
- Installing hamcrest/hamcrest-php (v2.0.1): Extracting archive
- Installing mockery/mockery (1.5.1): Extracting archive
- Installing filp/whoops (2.14.6): Extracting archive
- Installing nunomaduro/collision (v6.4.0): Extracting archive
- Installing sebastian/version (3.0.2): Extracting archive
- Installing sebastian/type (3.2.1): Extracting archive
- Installing sebastian/resource-operations (3.0.3): Extracting archive
- Installing sebastian/recursion-context (4.0.5): Extracting archive
- Installing sebastian/object-reflector (2.0.4): Extracting archive
- Installing sebastian/object-enumerator (4.0.4): Extracting archive
- Installing sebastian/global-state (5.0.5): Extracting archive
- Installing sebastian/exporter (4.0.5): Extracting archive
- Installing sebastian/environment (5.1.5): Extracting archive
- Installing sebastian/diff (4.0.4): Extracting archive
- Installing sebastian/comparator (4.0.8): Extracting archive
- Installing sebastian/code-unit (1.0.8): Extracting archive
- Installing sebastian/cli-parser (1.0.1): Extracting archive
- Installing phpunit/php-timer (5.0.3): Extracting archive
- Installing phpunit/php-text-template (2.0.4): Extracting archive
- Installing phpunit/php-invoker (3.1.1): Extracting archive
- Installing phpunit/php-file-iterator (3.0.6): Extracting archive
- Installing theseer/tokenizer (1.2.1): Extracting archive
- Installing sebastian/lines-of-code (1.0.3): Extracting archive
- Installing sebastian/complexity (2.0.2): Extracting archive
- Installing sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup (2.0.3): Extracting archive
- Installing phpunit/php-code-coverage (9.2.24): Extracting archive
- Installing phar-io/version (3.2.1): Extracting archive
- Installing phar-io/manifest (2.0.3): Extracting archive
- Installing myclabs/deep-copy (1.11.0): Extracting archive
- Installing doctrine/instantiator (2.0.0): Extracting archive
- Installing phpunit/phpunit (9.6.3): Extracting archive
- Installing spatie/backtrace (1.2.1): Extracting archive
- Installing spatie/flare-client-php (1.3.5): Extracting archive
- Installing spatie/ignition (1.4.3): Extracting archive
- Installing spatie/laravel-ignition (1.6.4): Extracting archive
  17/108 [====>-----------------------]  15%    Failed to extract laravel/pint: (9) C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin\unzip.EXE -qq C:\xampp\htdocs\EduOnline\vendor\composer\tmp-a6b6108ab5145ca169d3ac067b3695b6 -d C:\xampp\htdocs\EduOnline\vendor\composer\16d12e78

[C:/xampp/htdocs/EduOnline/vendor/composer/tmp-a6b6108ab5145ca169d3ac067b3695b6]
End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in C:/xampp/htdocs/EduOnline/vendor/composer/tmp-a6b6108ab5145ca169d3ac067b3695b6,
and cannot find C:/xampp/htdocs/EduOnline/vendor/composer/tmp-a6b6108ab5145ca169d3ac067b3695b6.zip, period.

```
The archive may contain identical file names with different capitalization (which fails on case insensitive filesystems)
Unzip with unzip command failed, falling back to ZipArchive class
```

Deprecation Notice: ZipArchive::open(): Using empty file as ZipArchive is deprecated in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Downloader/ZipDownloader.php:187
Install of laravel/pint failed
108/108 [============================] 100%

[RuntimeException]
Could not delete C:\xampp\htdocs\EduOnline/vendor/composer/tmp-a6b6108ab5145ca169d3ac067b3695b6:
This can be due to an antivirus or the Windows Search Indexer locking the file while they are analyzed

create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--add-repository] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--ask] [--] [] [] []

how to solution this problem

Answer (score 0):

- Remove `"laravel/pint": "^1.0",` from `composer.json`
- Delete `composer.lock`
- Run `composer install`

```
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0"
    },
```

This Should resolve the problem.